# How to ignore all the script and style tags from parent in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having a sample HTML on which I'm writing an XPath to extract content. And my main clause is to ignore `style` and `script` tags in it irrespective of the position and I want to do it from the parent itself. Here is my test block.

```
 <div itemprop="articleBody"> 
   <div>Main text.</div> 
   <p>
 <style type="text/css"> 
         #pStule{ 
         font-size: 10pt; 
         line-height: 15pt; 
         } 
    </style> 
sub text.</p> 
   <style type="text/css"> 
         #dhtmltooltip{ 
         font-size: 10pt; 
         line-height: 15pt; 
         } 
    </style> 
    <script> 
         var offsetxpoint=-60; 
         var offsetypoint=20;     
    </script> 
   <p>Another subtext.</p> 
</div>
```

and my Xpath is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
 <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::div[@itemprop='articleBody']/descendant::*[not(descendant::style) and not(descendant::script) and not(self::style) and not(self::script)]
"/> 
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am aware that we can achieve this using an `xsl:for-each` and doing the stuff inside it. But my program only accepts 1 line of XPath, that's the reason I want to do it from the parent.

My current output is

> Main text.Another subtext.

Expected output.

> Main text.sub text.Another subtext.

Currently, my `p` is getting ignored as it has a `style` tag inside it. Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: The approach followed by filtering with descendant ('not (descendant::style)') will not work to cover your case. Perhaps your program that outputs the result nodes should be responsible to filter again sub-elements instead. So your program might have to introduce another select to supply.  It seems you don't have the option to add your own templates matching the whitelisted elements, because here it would work eventually.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting text nodes inside of script or style elements you can use e.g.

```
//*[not(self::script | self::style)]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't provided your desired output, it's not completely clear what you're trying achieve. My proposed XPath is based on the assumption you want to extract *just the text value* of the document, excluding the textual content of the `script` and `style` elements.

```
//text()[not(parent::script)][not(parent::style)]
```